# Ubuntu 19.04 dummy output

Tags: sound, 19.04

I can't hear any sounds on my newly installed Ubuntu 19.04, all I get from the menu "sounds" is a Dummy output. What should I do?

Comment: or `cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa`

Answer (score 1):

Install music packages of rhythmbox and juk.

```
sudo apt install rhythmbox juk
```

These package have some additional audio drivers.

If that doesn't work try the official Ubuntu [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

Comment: The result is too long to be posted for the standard of this forum, is there any part of it that you need me to post? My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad E580

Comment: The lanptop model is Lenovo Thinkpad E580 is all I need to know. I can Google the rest.